# Unexpected slowdown with inner for loop parallelization using OpenMP on Intel compiler

Tags: openmp, icc

I am writing a program for a physical simulation.  I am receiving an unexpected slowdown when parallelizing an inner for loop when compiling with the Intel C++ compiler (icpc). The gist of the code is as follows:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++){
    calculate m here
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int j = 0; j < 3*npos; j++) {
        pos[j] += 2*m[j];
    }
}
```

Where `m[j]` is a random number within a specified interval and `pos` is an array of particle positions.  At first, I thought the slowdown was due to the creation and destruction of the threads during each of the outer loop iterations.  If this were the case, the slowdown would be less significant if the work of the inner loop were more extensive.  However, I found the scale of the slowdown to be constant when `npos` is increased from 1,000 to 10,000, adding to my confusion.
To put this in perspective, I am running about 12s in serial while 18s in parallel when `npos` = 1,000 and about 120s in serial and 180s in parallel when `npos`=10,000.  If anyone could clue me in on what might be causing this slowdown, that would be appreciated.

I am compiling using: icpc -qopenmp -03

--Update--:  Reverting the code for compatibility and compiling with g++, the code is parallelized and speedups are acquired as expected. The slowdown only occurs when using the same code, compiled with Intel's icpc. Therefore, I must be missing something about using OMP with Intel compilers.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the execution times of both versions but compiling with -O0?

Comment: Are you checking e.g. by -qopt-report4 for simd vectorization in both cases? Nominally, by leaving off the simd clause you are disabling simd when adding thread parallelism.  You also neglected to say whether you set omp_places=cores and tried setting omp_num_threads to number of cores.  If you run on a single CPU omp doesn't boost memory bandwidth.

Comment: I wonder if this code is too much summarized. Do you calculate `m` only once before going into these two-nested loops? Or do you calculate it for every innermost iteration?

Comment: Could you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?